# Javascript timezone bug between Feb 9, 1942-Sept 30 1945

Tags: javascript, datetime, dst

I have a Date from Jan 13, 1943 at 4:00am UTC.  It's being converted by Javascript to Jan 12, 1943 11:00PM EST (GMT-500).  However, according to [Day Light Savings Time history](http://www.infoplease.com/askeds/daylight-saving-time.html) for the USA the period between Feb 9, 1942-Sept 30, 1945 was permanently DST.  My server handles this correctly inserting a Date into the DB with GMT-400 or 4:00AM UTC.  However, Javascript seems to assume dates between Nov 1st and March 8th are always GMT-500 regardless of the year.  And hence we get a rounding error on certain Dates falling between these periods.  Can anyone confirm this is a problem with Javascript's Timezones?

Comment: This largely depends on who's curated your time-zone data files. I'm not sure they've created historical records for any events prior to the epoch January 1, 1970. Finding records on which states and towns were or were not on DST would be quite an exercise, especially when very few people would care

Comment: Wow, where is Jon Skeet when you need him?